# ifconfig to disable part of an extension

Tags: magento-2.2.5, system.xml, custom-column-grid, di.xml

I have added a Column to the New Order -> Customer Grid. I am having a really tough time getting the system config to disable this code if turned off. I was hoping I could use a simple ifconfig in the `sales_order_create_customer_block.xml` or the `di.xml` to check but it does not work. I have tried calling `isNewOrderCustomerGridEnabled()` as an `if` before but I get a `cannot be null error`.

In the other grids, I added the column with a Plugin and the ui_component xml. Which I was able to add a specific class `Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Company.php` which checks the Data.php and displays the information depending on the system config setting.

Here is some of the code. Please let me know if you need any more information.

`sales_order_create_customer_block.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.customer.grid.container">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Trucatch\CompanyColumn\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.customer.grid.columnSet">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="billing_company" after="name">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Company</argument>
                    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">billing_company</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

`di.xml`

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection" type="Trucatch\CompanyColumn\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection"/>
```

`Data.php`

```
const CONFIG_PATH_GENERAL_NEW_ORDER_CUSTOMER_GRID = 'companycolumn/general/new_order_customer_grid_enabled';

public function isNewOrderCustomerGridEnabled()
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        self::CONFIG_PATH_GENERAL_NEW_ORDER_CUSTOMER_GRID,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```

`Collection.php`

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $this->joinAttribute(
        'billing_company',
        'customer_address/company',
        'default_billing',
        null,
        'left'
    );
    return $this;
}
```